# How to log inputstream to file in android and then parse it

Tags: java, android

I am receiving an InputStream from HttpUrlConnection (connection.getInputStream()), and I am parsing the input stream using DocumentBuilder (documenbtBuilder.parse(inputStream)). Before parsing, I want to write the received data to log file. When I do that, I get org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Unexpected end of document Exception in the parse method. My code works fine if I don't write to file, but I need to log the data received.

Please find the code that writes to file below :

```
  final InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();

    writeLogInfo(input);

    Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(input);

    //Method that writes tito log file.

    private void writeLogInfo(InputStream input){

     OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("mylogfile.txt");

     byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

     int byteRead;

     while((byteRead = input.read(buffer)) != -1){
        os.write(buffer,0,byteRead);
     }

     os.flush();

     os.close();

   }
```

I suspect it is because of multiple use of InputStream, since the code works when I don't invode writeLogInfo(). I am not closing the inputstream anywhere in my code. What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Indeed, you can't doubly use the InputStream like that.  You have basically three options:  1) Fetch your data twice 2) Write your data to a file, then open a FileInputStream and read it back in to parse.  3) Make your own wrapper class which implements InputStream, wrap it around the source one so that its read() calls the source read() and logs the resulting data before giving it to the parser which as the ultimate consumer will control the pacing of reads.

Answer (score 0):

When you are writing the content to a file, you are reaching the end of the inputstream.

So after that, when you are trying to parse, you get the exception.

You need to use `mark` and `reset` methods on the inputstream before passing it to documentbuilder.

Also, first you need to check if the input stream supports mark.

Here is the javadoc, for your reference

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html

Comment: I'd be a little surprised if an InputStream sourced from the network supports rewinding.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the size of the file is under 1024 bytes. If not why don't you put your "inputstream" to BufferredInputstream, and create the byte array..

```
BufferedInputStream bin= new BufferedInputStream(new DataInputStream(input));
byte[] buffer= new byte[bin.available()];
bin.read(buffer);
os.write(buffer);
......
......
bin.close();
......
```

Comment: That it's probably not less than the buffer size is the reason the read & write operations are performed in a while loop - but this has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: @ kaze. I tried your approach but the file is empty. I cannot close the inputstream (bin.close()) since I am using it again to parse it. Also I logged the length of buffer. It is not empty. So the bin contains data but the file is empty.

Comment: @kaze. nope. The inputstream is not reset when it is parsed. It throws Unexpected end of document exception. I tried to get the data using new InputSource(connection.getInputStream()) while parsing but that does not work either.